# RegEx find text within / surrounded by string(s) | Pattern.matches() == false

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a the following `json` string, which I have to filter to get the so called raw sentence.

> {"subscribe":["message","sentence","*ANYTEXTWITHANYLENGTHHEREINCLUDINGNUMBERSDOTS*;\r\n\"]}

Deserialization of the `json` `string` is not allowed!

I did filter the searched text with the following `regular expression`:

```
((?<=\{\"subscribe\":\[\"message\",\"sentence\",")(.*)(?=;))
```

or (since it has to be escaped in the java code):

```
String pattern = "(?<=\\{\"subscribe\":\\[\"message\",\"sentence\",\")(.*)(?=;)";
```

This is working perfectly if I use `Matcher.find()` and iterate within a `while` statement:

```
while (_regexMatcher.find()) {
    matches.add(_regexMatcher.group()); //Add to List<String>
}
```

Unfortunately the whole code is given by our professor. He did surround the whole code with:

```
if (Pattern.matches(pattern, json)) {
     ... 
}
```

Since `Pattern.matches()` uses the pattern with `^` in the beginnen of the whole pattern and `$` at the ending, so it won't find any matches. 
Is there another way to get the *ANYTEXTWITHANYLENGTHHEREINCLUDINGNUMBERSDOTS* so `Pattern.matches()` returns true?

Comment: is the mistake in JSON intentional or just a typo?

Comment: If you are always certain of the format of the rest of your pseudo-`JSON` aside from the desired string, it would seem the simplest solution probably would involves using some combination of `.split("/"")` and/or `.split(",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
[\s\S]*(?<=\{"subscribe":\["message","sentence",")(.*)(?=;)[\s\S]*
```

the `[\s\S]*` will match anything before and after, so the whole string will be matched, but only if there will be `(?<=\{"subscribe":\["message","sentence",")(.*)(?=;)` inside.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it surely works :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (in_file.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        one_line = in_file.nextLine();

        tokens = one_line.split("\\P{Alpha}+");
        for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) 
        {
            //do whatever;
        }
```

more detailed info here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add .*? in front of your regular expression. It will match reluctantly (by opposition with the greedy .*), which means it will stop matching as soon as it reaches your previous json pattern, which should work as previously